# friend and template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, shadow, friend

I have a big problem in my C++ Code example. There is something wrong with 'friend' and the 'template'.

**Error Messages:**
*Matrix.h:26:79: warning:*

> friend declaration 'std::ostream&
>   matrixClass::operator<<(std::ostream&, const matrixClass::Matrix&)'
>   declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>           friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix &matrix);

*Matrix.h:26:79: note:*

> ```
>   (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template
> ```
>
> has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)

*Matrix.h:28:77: warning:*

> ```
>   friend declaration 'matrixClass::Matrix<T>*
> ```
>
> matrixClass::operator*(const matrixClass::Matrix&, const
>   matrixClass::Matrix&)' declares a non-template function
>   [-Wnon-template-friend]
>           friend Matrix* operator*(const Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2);

*Matrix.cpp:1:0:*

> C:\Users\Peter\CLionProjects\PK\untitled76\Matrix.h:26:79: warning:
>         friend declaration 'std::ostream&
>   matrixClass::operator<<(std::ostream&, const matrixClass::Matrix&)'
>   declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>           friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix &matrix);

*Matrix.h:26:79: note:*

> ```
>   (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template
> ```
>
> has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)

*Matrix.h:28:77: warning:*

> ```
>   friend declaration 'matrixClass::Matrix<T>*
> ```
>
> matrixClass::operator*(const matrixClass::Matrix&, const
>   matrixClass::Matrix&)' declares a non-template function
>   [-Wnon-template-friend]
>           friend Matrix* operator*(const Matrix &m1, const Matrix &m2);

*CMakeFiles\untitled76.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':*

main.cpp:8: undefined reference to
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `matrixClass::Matrix<int>::Matrix(int)'<br>
main.cpp:10: undefined reference to`matrixClass::Matrix::set(int, int, int)'
main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `matrixClass::Matrix<int>::set(int, int, int)'<br>
main.cpp:12: undefined reference to`matrixClass::Matrix::set(int, int, int)'
main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `matrixClass::Matrix<int>::set(int, int, int)'<br>
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to`matrixClass::operator<<(std::ostream&, matrixClass::Matrix const&)'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `matrixClass::operator<<(std::ostream&, matrixClass::Matrix<int> const&)'<br>
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to`matrixClass::Matrix::~Matrix()'
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `matrixClass::Matrix::~Matrix()'

**Code:**
*Matrix.h*

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_

#include <iostream>

namespace matrixClass {

    template<class T>
    class Matrix {
    private:
        int dimension;
        T **m;
    public:
        Matrix(int d);

        Matrix(const Matrix &original);

        ~Matrix();

        void set(int x, int y, T value);

        T get(int x, int y) const;

        int getDimension() const;

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<T> &matrix);

        friend Matrix<T>* operator*(const Matrix<T> &m1, const Matrix<T> &m2);
    };
}

#endif
```

*Matrix.cpp*

```
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace matrixClass;

template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int d)
        : dimension{d}, m{new T *[d]} {
    //m = new T*[d];

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        m[i] = new T[d];
    }
}

// COPY-CONSTRUCTOR
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix &original)
        : dimension{original.dimension},
          m{new T *[original.dimension]} {
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        *(m + i) = *(original.m + i);
    }
}

// DESTRUCTOR
template<class T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        delete[] m[i];
    }
    delete[] m;
}

template<class T>
void Matrix<T>::set(int x, int y, T value) {
    m[x][y] = value;
}

template<class T>
T Matrix<T>::get(int x, int y) const {
    return m[x][y];
}

template<class T>
int Matrix<T>::getDimension() const {
    return dimension;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    int dimension = matrix.getDimension();

    for(int x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < dimension; y++) {
            output << matrix.get(x, y) << " ";
        }
        return output;
    }
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T>* operator*(const Matrix<T>& m1, const Matrix<T>& m2) {
    int dimension = m1.getDimension();
    Matrix<T>* m = new Matrix<T>(dimension);

    for(int x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < dimension; y++) {
            T value = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
                value += m1.get(x, i) * m2.get(i, y);
            }
            m->set(x, y, value);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace matrixClass;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Matrix<int> m(2);

    m.set(0, 0, 1);
    m.set(0, 1, 2);
    m.set(1, 0, 3);
    m.set(1, 1, 4);

    cout << m << "*" << endl << m << "=" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The template (in your situation Matrix) should have all the declarations and definitions in the header file. Try with that first.

Comment: Full error output; it's not minimal; but for saying more than "it's not working", have an upvote

Comment: Make your friend functions also templates and better move the templated member functions in the header

Comment: `*(m + i) = *(original.m + i)` will share memory between original and copy. Their destruction will delete twice these memory areas.

Comment: @O'Neil what do you mean? Do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @PeterHerrlich Make a copy of a matrix, modify the copy and print the original. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: And the `operator*` shouldn't return a pointer, just a `Matrix<T>`.

Comment: @O'Neil it will change the whole code.

Comment: @PeterHerrlich That's quite exaggerated ;)

Comment: @O'Neil can you tell me what I have to change, please. I'm a beginner :-)

Comment: @PeterHerrlich This exact line. You have to allocate memory for every `m[i]`, then copy all values from the original matrix to all of the `m[i][j]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `friend` declaration `operator<<` refers to a non-template function, while its definition says it's a template function; they don't match.

You can define it inline with the `friend` declaration (as non-template function):

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
    ... ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
        int dimension = matrix.getDimension();

        for(int x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < dimension; y++) {
                output << matrix.get(x, y) << " ";
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
    ... ...
};
```

Or make the `friend` declaration referring to the function template:

```
// class declaration
template<class T>
class Matrix;

// function declaration
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<T>& matrix);

// class definition
template<class T>
class Matrix {
    ... ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<T>& matrix);
    ... ...
};

// function definition
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<T>& matrix) {
    int dimension = matrix.getDimension();

    for(int x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < dimension; y++) {
            output << matrix.get(x, y) << " ";
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

And about the undefined reference error, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Comment: Tried as inline but still have error lile undefined reference to `matrixClass::Matrix<int>::Matrix(int)

Comment: @PeterHerrlich Did you see the post I linked? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend has similar example. Interesting that this could also be solved not only with a _friend template_ but also with a  with _template friend_.

Comment: @A.A Note there's difference; template friend declaration makes all the instantiations of the function template friend of the class. Well if that matches OP's intent too then it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the problem with your non-member `operator<<()` and `operator*()` using Friend Templates, which is slightly different from making an instance of a function template a friend (the second solution presented by @songyuanyao). The difference is that with a Friend Template, all instances of the template function are friends of the class `Matrix<>`. In this case, I don't think there is any practical difference, but in others, there may be. Therefore, I figured I'd present it anyway.

I think about it like this. Both operators are non-member functions which means they are independent from the class `Matrix<>`, so think of their prototypes independently:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<T>& matrix);

template<class T>
Matrix<T>* operator*(const Matrix<T>& m1, const Matrix<T>& m2);
```

Now, replace `T` with `U` because to make all instances of them friends of `Matrix<>`, their prototype needs to be included in the class definition for `Matrix<>` which is also a template, and it is already using `T` as its template parameter.

```
template<class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<U>& matrix);

template<class U>
Matrix<U>* operator*(const Matrix<U>& m1, const Matrix<U>& m2);
```

Now, you can make them friends of `Matrix<>`. All you need is the appropriate syntax:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    ...
    template<class U>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<U> &matrix);

    template<class U>
    friend Matrix<U>* operator*(const Matrix<U> &m1, const Matrix<U> &m2);
};
```

Finally, they all need to be within the `matrixClass` `namespace`, and their declarations and definitions need to be in the right order so that everyone know the others exists:

```
namespace matrixClass {

// BEGIN Forward declarations

template<class T>
class Matrix;

template<class U>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<U> &matrix);

template<class U>
Matrix<U>* operator*(const Matrix<U> &m1, const Matrix<U> &m2);

// END Forward declarations

template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    ...
    template<class U>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<U> &matrix);

    template<class U>
    friend Matrix<U>* operator*(const Matrix<U> &m1, const Matrix<U> &m2);
};

...

template<class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Matrix<U>& matrix)
{
    ...   // your implementation goes here
}

template<class U>
Matrix<U>* operator*(const Matrix<U>& m1, const Matrix<U>& m2)
{
    ...   // your implementation goes here
}

}   // end of namespace matrixClass
```

All this template code should be in the header file, Matrix.h, as it has already been mentioned.

Also, I think that you should change the prototype of `operator*()` to return `Matrix<U>` instead of `Matrix<U>*`. It will behave more like the normal `operator*()`, and it'll enable you to do things like: `Matrix<int> m = m1*m2;` or `m = m1*m2*m3;`. Additionally, the users of your class won't have to worry about deleting the memory allocated by `operator*()` or the performance cost of the dynamic allocation. Just create a local `Matrix<U>` variable in `operator*()` and return it by value; let Return Value Optimization (RVO) take care of the rest.